# Terminal Command Doesn't Finish

Tags: python, terminal, command

I have a command in terminal which doesn't finish. I mean it's not like "ls" which after executing finishes. I am using this command in my python code, so I need it to finish ! because I have to proceed. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What do you *mean* it "doesn't finish"? What does it *do*?

Comment: The command mounts a drive. When you run it, it stucks. The only to continue is killing the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can just use Python's `Popen` to create a child process and then not wait for the child process to complete

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html